# ViewpageIndicator library manual tab change?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

We have used the viewpageindicator library in our app, we would like to know how the tabs can be opened manually/programatically?

Thanks in advance,
Abhilash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Call `setCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29). If you have hooked up the indicator properly, it will change as the page changes.

Comment: Awesome! I wasted days searching on how to achieve this! Worked like a charm. Thank you!! Saved my day